# Criteria to classify retail customers as churn Y or N

Tags: classification, churn

I have retail transactions data set. some of the attributes are CUSTID, BILL_DT, ITEM_Desc, VALUE. I want to classify the custid as churn y or n. Should i use the days between last purchase date till now as a criteria to classify? Can i say anything beyond 180 days that customer has churned? What is the criteria which the big retailers like costco, walmart uses?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

From the transaction data, you could extract history consisting of a sequence of the pair (time elapsed since last transaction, amount spent in current transaction). If you know which customers have actually churned, you could build a predictive model using the Markov Chain classifier.

https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/customer-conversion-prediction-with-markov-chain-classifier/